# Given $\Bbb N$ can you reach every infinite cardinal by performing succesive power set operations?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $X$ is a set with $|X|=\mathcal K\geq \aleph_0$.

Does it always exist an $n$ such that $|\mathcal P (\mathcal P(\cdots\mathcal P(\mathcal (P (\Bbb N ))\cdots)|\geq\mathcal K$ (where the power set is taken $n$ times)?

I believe the answer will be no, but I don't know near enough set theory to prove this.

E: Meant $\geq$ instead of $=\,$ !

Comment: @AndresMejia: I don't see how that is relevant at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take the power set only a finite number of times, the answer is no, let 
$$ \def\P{\mathscr P}\P^\omega(\mathbf N) := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbf N} \P^n(\mathbf N) $$
Then, for any $n$, we have 
$$ |\P^n(\mathbf N)| < |\P^{n+1}(\mathbf N)| \le |\P^\omega(\mathbf N)| $$